# Alexa, there was an issue processing your input

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm following a video which explain how to create a skill and intents, to use Alexa. (Here is the link to see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMb0y66UCxs)

I have a problem, I can't go inside an Intent but I can run the skill with the sentence "Alexa open [Name of the skill]". I will show you the index.js from aws and after that the JSON file from developer amazon.

AWS
[image: Aws_image]

And here, the JSON:
[image: developper_amazone_image]

I built this project in english in the developer amazon website, but i live in france. Maybe I can have a conflict there. And i also choose, in aws, the city east USA (virginia...). So when i say : ask [name of the skill] for [Un unterance], i have this problem:

[image: test_in_developer_amazone_website]

When I click on the exclamation point, it says: "There was an issue processing your input". Do you see my problem ?

Comment: Please do not post images of your code but put it directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, and I could be wrong, but do you need to add a GetNewFactHandler? It doesn't look like you defined one anywhere and your trying to add it in .addRequestHandlers.

Based on the other handlers in your code I'm guessing it should look something like this:

```
const GetNewFactHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'GetNewFact'
  }, 
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder 
      .speak('Hello from the get new fact intent')
      .getResponse()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry, I just forgot to put the part where I have this code in my aws.
[The forgotten part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBMv9.png)